# tex4ebook: module char-def not found

Tags: tex4ebook, make4ht, ebook

I'm trying to typeset a multi-chapter book for use with Kindle.
Hence, I'm looking to use tex4ebook.

I got this error:

```
tex4ebook  book.tex 
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: book.tex
...xmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/domfilters/make4ht-sectionid.lua:4: module 'char-def' not found:
    no field package.preload['char-def']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'char-def'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'char-def'
```

How do I install char-def? Which package is this?

Comment: Do you use development version of make4ht? The `make4ht-sectionid.lua` file is not part of TeX Live yet. Anyway, `char-def.lua` in included in Context.

Comment: @michal.h21 yes, I used the development version because I needed xelatex support.

Comment: XeLaTeX support should work out of the box. But I will update the development version to check if `char-def` is available. The feature it enables is not critical, so the compilation shouldn't fail because of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @michal.h21 !

Comment: I've updated `make4ht` development version. It shouldn't fail now.

Comment: @michal.h21 it works now (a warning is output, no error). Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is great that it works! the warning is here to tell that not everything works as expected, but it is just missing one feature, nothing critical. I think you can close this question now .)